# Guardar imagen obtenida de una respuesta get

Tags: javascript, nodejs, axios

Estoy haciendo una peticion GET a un servicio para traer una imagen. Usando la libreria axios desde NodeJS.

```
axios
  .get("RUTA_DE_LA_IMAGEN")
  .then(res => {
    /*Como guardar la imagen obtenida*/
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("err");
  });
```

Me pregunto como puedo guargar la imagen obtenida en la respuesta en mi sistema de ficheros, con una ruta indicada y nombre personalizado.
Supongo que tendra algo que ver con el modulo fs de node, pero no logre encontrar nada.

Answer (score 0):

¿La imagen que obtienes con axios la deseas guardar localmente, o deseas mandarla a otro lugar mediante otra api?

Lo imagino de esta forma , ya que es muy poco codigo el que proporcionas.

```
var path = require('path');

axios
  .get("RUTA_DE_LA_IMAGEN")
  .then(res => {
    var staticBasePath = './RUTA_TUYA'; //images
    var resolvedBase = path.resolve(staticBasePath);
    var fileloc = path.join(resolveBase,res.data.image);
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.write(fileloc);
    return res.end();

  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("err");
  });
```

Comment: La quiero guardar localmente, en el directorio que le especifique